# Are there any good database management apps for Mac for MongoDB? Similar to Sequel Pro?

Tags: mongodb, database

Looking for a GUI that visualizes collections and documents in mongodb.

Comment: I can answer because someone gave me a good answer over on hashnode. They recommended robomongo(https://robomongo.org/) which I've been using and love.

Comment: same reason people create this question.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of tools available over the web

1. [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) is the best and most famous
2. [MongoClient](http://www.mongoclient.com/)
3. [MongoTron](http://mongotron.io/#/)
4. [3T mongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/)
5. [Mongo Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass?jmp=docs&_ga=1.32872446.17164595.1474058029) to visualize and analyse the data

[More Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/)